# Flex DisplayObject in fullscreen mode

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, charts, fullscreen

I would like to make a display object fullscreen in my Flex application. I understand it is easy to make the complete Stage fullscreen in flex [(example)](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/). But I have two charts on my Stage and I would like to make one of the charts full screen on clicking a button (or on double clicking on the chart area) and as per my understanding a ColumnChart is a DisplayObject [(API reference)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/ColumnChart.html).

Is it possible to do so? and if it is possible then please post the code snippet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I do in cases like this is use the Flex HDividedBox containing two containers of your choice. Then you can make the HDividedBox 100% x 100%; and hide or show the two containers as you choose.

It makes a pretty nice book-with-split-pages emulator. It also makes it easy use the divider bar to drag-resize the relative split between the two, so an image can scale smoothly, for instance.

I use TabNavigators on the left and right sides, making it easy to riffle through page-like tabs on each side.

Answer (score 0):

see:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html
just set a fullscreen source rectangle to your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this ...

```
private var myLeftColumnChart : ColumnChart;
private var myRightColumnChart : ColumnChart;

private function onButtonClick() : void{
   myRightColumnChart.visible = myRightColumnChart.includeInLayout = false;

   myLeftColumnChart.y = myLeftColumnChart.x = 0;
   myLeftColumnChart.width = Application.application.width;
   myRightColumnChart.height = Application.application.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fullScreenSourceRect property on stage and set it to the Rectangle that has the position of the chart that you want to show in full screen.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that but for some reason the aspect ratios are not the same as the screen resolution and it gives me scroll bars which makes it look absolutely hideous. Have you had that issue?